# Calling a REST API using Azure function App

Tags: azure, function, api, rest

I want to call a REST API using Azure function App. REST API uses basic authentication and does not need any request parameters. The result of this API call need to be saved to ADLS gen2 blob storage. Below is the step 1 of the code where I am trying to call the REST API from function App. When I try to debug the code, response has 403 message. Any help is appreciated

```
            string url = String.Format("my_rest_end_point_url");
            HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            newRequest.Headers.Authorization =
                 new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                     "Basic",
                     Convert.ToBase64String(
                         System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                             string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "pwd"))));

            //Read Server Response
            string responseMessage = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await newClient.SendAsync(newRequest);
            log.LogInformation("RESPONSE.", response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString());
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
```

Comment: The 403 forbidden error message means you don't have enough permissions. Have you check the username and password can access to the rest api? If you use function app's username and password to auth rest api, it may cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have verified the credentials. I am able to call the REST API using postman with the same credentials

Comment: I test your code in my site with console app and function app, both of them work well. Can you try to call the rest api in the console app? Or try to create a new function and try again?